# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'services_backend.routes.models.category.CategoryCreate' is not mapped

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am using pydantic, fastapi+sqlalchemy and postgresql for my project. When i`m trying to create new button (or category), i get UnmappedInstanceError.

Here is my code:

button.py (from routes)

```
from fastapi import HTTPException, APIRouter
from fastapi_sqlalchemy import db

from .models.button import ButtonCreate, ButtonUpdate, ButtonGet
from ..models.database import Button
from .category import get_category

button = APIRouter(
    tags=["button"],
    responses={200: {"description": "Ok"}}
)


@button.post("/", response_model=ButtonCreate)
def create_button(button: ButtonCreate):
    db_category = get_category(category_id=button.category_id)
    if db_category is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Category does not exist")
    db_button = ButtonCreate(category_id=button.category_id, name=button.name,
                             icon=button.icon)
    db.session.add(db_button)
    return db_button


@button.get("/", response_model=list[ButtonGet])
def get_buttons(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.session.query(Button).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()


@button.get("/{button_id}", response_model=ButtonGet)
def get_button(button_id: int):
    db_button = db.session.query(Button).filter(Button.id == button_id).first()
    if db_button is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Button does not exist")
    return db_button


@button.delete("/")
def remove_button(button_id: int):
    db_button = get_button(button_id=button_id)
    if db_button is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Button does not exist")
    db.session.query(Button).filter(Button.id == button_id).first()


@button.patch("/", response_model=ButtonUpdate)
def update_button(button: ButtonUpdate):
    db_old_button = get_button(button_id=button.id)
    if db_old_button is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Button does not exist")
    return db.session.query(Button).update(button)
```

button.py (from models, my schemas)

```
from .base import Base
from typing import Optional


class ButtonCreate(Base):
    category_id: int
    icon: Optional[str]
    name: Optional[str]


class ButtonUpdate(Base):
    id: int
    category_id: Optional[int]
    icon: Optional[str]
    name: Optional[str]


class ButtonGet(Base):
    id: int
```

All of my schemas are inherited from custom Base class (which inherited from BaseModel)

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Base(BaseModel):
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        attrs = []
        for k, v in self.__class__.schema().items():
            attrs.append(f"{k}={v}")
        return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join(attrs))

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: you're trying to use `CategoryCreate` as an ORM model, when it is a pydantic model (I'm guessing, you haven't included it here). Same in your `create_button` function, you're trying to add a `ButtonCreate` object to the database. That should be the ORM model `Button` instead.